# Where is java installed on Mac. I can't find it

Tags: java, macos, path, installation

I have successfully installed java. When I type in the terminal:

`java -version`

I get: `java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14`. But I don't know where it is installed.

When I type :

`echo $(/usr/libexec/java_home)`

to get the path it shows me: `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home` but in the folder `Library` isn't the folder Java : `-bash: cd: Java: No such file or directory*`

Answer (score 17):

Execute the following command on Mac Terminal:

```
/usr/libexec/java_home -V
```

It will show you all the versions of JDK installed in your Mac.

Now, let's say it shows you paths like as given below:

```
/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-14.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home
```

Execute the following command:

```
cd /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/
ls
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply, type `java -verbose` in terminal, you will get the java installation location in the first line.

Answer (score 1):

Successful result of commands on my Mac:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Install Java
2. java -version
   openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18 LTS
   OpenJDK Runtime Environment AppleJDK-17.0.5.8.2 (build 17.0.5+8-LTS)
   OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM AppleJDK-17.0.5.8.2 (build 17.0.5+8-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)
3. whereis java
   java: /usr/bin/java
4. /usr/libexec/java_home -V
   Matching Java Virtual Machines (6):
   17.0.5.8.2 (x86_64) "Apple Inc." - "AppleJDK 17" /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/applejdk-17.0.5.8.2.jdk/Contents/Home
5. This is the Java installed location /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/applejdk-17.0.5.8.2.jdk/Contents/Home